# Altering A Twilio Function to trigger 2 webhook endpoints (Missive & GoHighLevel) For Handling Incoming MMS

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to receive MMS in Missive App and GoHighLevel via my twilio function.

I am using this twilio function to trigger multiple webhook endpoints for Missive App and GoHighLevel.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('querystring');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();

  let { 
      ApiVersion,
      SmsSid,
      SmsStatus,
      SmsMessageSid,
      NumSegments,
      ToState,
      From,
      MessageSid,
      AccountSid,
      ToCity,
      FromCountry,
      ToZip,
      FromCity,
      To,
      FromZip,
      ToCountry,
      Body,
      NumMedia,
      FromState 
  } = event;

  let requestBody = {
      ApiVersion,
      SmsSid,
      SmsStatus,
      SmsMessageSid,
      NumSegments,
      ToState,
      From,
      MessageSid,
      AccountSid,
      ToCity,
      FromCountry,
      ToZip,
      FromCity,
      To,
      FromZip,
      ToCountry,
      Body,
      NumMedia,
      FromState 
  };

    let url1 = "https://example.com/1";
    let url2 = "https://example.com/2";

   const config = {
     headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
     }};

  Promise.all([
       axios.post(url1, qs.stringify(requestBody), config),
       axios.post(url2, qs.stringify(requestBody), config)
       ]).then(result => {
           callback(null, twiml);
       }).catch(err => {
           console.log(err);
           callback(err);
       });
};
```

The inbound and outbound SMS are working fine, but when I receive inbound MMS, the messages have no content. I am trying to handle the MMS so that they are also passed onto Missive App and GoHighLevel.

Comment: I am noticing that sometimes the incoming MMS shows up with no content and other times the MMS does not appear at all. In either case, the MMS is still showing on my twilio message logs but not passing though to the webhooks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Axios docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example), the ".then" for multiple concurrent requests should use this pattern:

```
Promise.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(function ([acct, perm]) {
    // ...
  });
```

Try this:

```
Promise.all([
       axios.post(url1, qs.stringify(requestBody), config),
       axios.post(url2, qs.stringify(requestBody), config)
       ]).then(function ([p1, p2]) {
           callback(null, twiml);
       }).catch(err => {
           console.log(err);
           callback(err);
       });
```

Comment: Thanks! I plugged this in exactly as is but MMS are still not showing any content. Did I need to alter the code you sent at at all or leave the p1 and p2 as is?

Comment: Your code seems to show that the twiml is empty and never populated with anything. "let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();" is essentially an empty response. You seem to be missing code to populate the twiml with a useful response. Such as "twiml.message(`Hello, Enjoy`)" If this is helpful, please accept this answer.

Comment: What code would I need to input there? Would this be something that impacts MMS only because SMS is working fine?

Comment: The code twiml.message(Hello, Enjoy)". In your code, there doesn't seem to be any MMS or SMS actually being sent. Is the number you are sending from MMS enabled? This page describes how to send MMS which is essentially SMS plus an attachment (picture, vard, etc.), but I do not think this is relevant to why your text messages are arriving empty: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179808-Sending-and-receiving-MMS-messages.

Comment: Yeah. The number is MMS enabled. I can send MMS no problem. The number itself also receives MMS. I know this because I can open them up on the twilio messaging log. So when I receive the MMS, the media is just not being passed onto the 2 webhooks properly and then appears as empty.

I'm still a little confused by the "twiml.message(Hello, Enjoy)" code. What should I insert instead of (Hello, Enjoy) ?

Comment: Here is how you send MMS with a picture: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages-node-js)

Comment: I'm not having issues with sending. I'm only having issues with receiving.

Comment: You should check the Twilio console logs to determine what was actually sent. You could also try the example code from Twilio to send a picture and confirm that you can receive those. If that works, the problem points to your code.

Comment: Yes. I can see the MMS in the Twilio console logs. I've tested it with the twilo sample code and everything works fine with MMS and SMS. The sample code passes data through a single webhook.

My code sends the data through 2 webhooks. It works fine for SMS, but not for MMS. I know my code is definitely the issue, but I don't know what to change.

Comment: Maybe try your two-webhook configuration using the Twilio sample code. This is about I'll can provide as far as suggestions and troubleshooting the destination (far) end not receiving MMS.